# Animate 2D RGB numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working on a LED-Wall with 24x30 Pixels for a while now.

At this point there is a Python server which can interpret and display numpy arrays in the following format:

```
frame = np.zeros([24, 30, 3])
```

That is, 24 pixels wide, 30 high, and 3 colors per LED. So this array would make the wall all black.

I made a few animations only on the array itself. But I really want to proceed with the following topics:

- Drawing on the wall (e.g. circles and other shapes).
- Animating the drawings.
- Displaying text.

My questions:

- How do I connect my `np.array` with `matplotlib` to do the drawings or animations?
- Is `matplotlib` even the right approach?
- What would be the best approach to display fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing images: 3D arrays with R, G and B channels in the last axis. Essentially you want to be able to draw images with Python. You have lots of options, but the one I'd probably reach for first is [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (confusingly, the library is called `PIL` but the package you install is `pillow`).

You can certainly make arbitrary images in `matplotlib`, with shapes, text, etc, but I feel like things will be easier with `PIL`. My advice is to start with a tutorial to get a feel for the API.

Here's how to make a black rectangle (like the example you gave):

```
from PIL import Image

h, w = 24, 30
im = Image.new("RGB", (w, h), "black")
```

Now I can write `Hi` in it, in cyan:

```
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype('/path/to/fonts/Consolas.ttf', size=18)  # Change this!
ImageDraw.Draw(im).text((5, 4),          # Position
                        'Hi',            # String
                        (0, 255, 255),   # Colour
                        font=font,       # Font
                       )
```

Of course you can save this as a PNG or GIF or whatever, or use something like [`imageio`](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/) to make an animated GIF. You can get the data as a NumPy array with `np.asarray(im)`. It uses unsigned `int8` values, so 0 to 255. You can rescale if you need, say, 0 to 1.